# Suggestions for continuous integration, test and deploy infrastructure for a Ruby on Rails application in Amazon EC2 cloud

Tags: automated-testing, continuous-integration

I would like to know everyone's opinion on the best tools for setting up a continuous integration, test and deploy infrastructure for a Ruby on Rails web application API in the Amazon EC2 cloud and any tips or best practices for Jenkins, JMeter, RubyMine, git ...

Comment: This is a very broad question.  Perhaps you could narrow it down by telling us what research you have already done on this subject and what specific issues arose from that research.

Answer (score 1):

I think [ci-infrastructure](https://github.com/winhamwr/ci-infrastructure) is what you are looking for. "Getting a fresh Jenkins server set up is kind of a pain and because of that, fewer projects have one than should. This project is designed to make it easy for people to fork and get set up with their very-own Jenkins server in the cloud because CI is awesome. "

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Railsonfire](http://railsonfire.com) (Full disclosure I am one of the founders)

We provide Continuous integration and Deployment for Ruby apps as a Cloud Service. Simple setup in < 2 minutes. If you need any help setting it up write me an email to flo@railsonfire.com, a tweet to @Railsonfire or use the olark chat box at the bottom of our site.

If you do want to use your own EC2 instances I would recommend https://github.com/defunkt/cijoe

as it is easy to set up and run. Jenkins is imho bloated, especially if you want to run ruby builds